# How do I calculate the next occurrence of a time 04:00 am EST?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

What is an efficient way to get the next occurrence of 04:00 am EST?

For example, if the date and time is 2013/11/19 01:30:00 then next occurrence would be 2013/11/19 04:00:00, however if it is 2013/11/19 17:00:00 then next occurrence would be 2013/11/20 04:00:00

Comment: Are you not concerned about time zones?

Comment: @AmolPujari I forgot to mention time zone thanks for reminding. I want for time zone :- EST.

Comment: hope its not across time zones

Comment: yes right, its not across the time zones. @AmolPujari

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try following

```
time = if Time.now.hour >= 4 
          Time.now+1.day 
       else
          Time.now
       end

time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d 04:00:00").to_datetime
```

OR Just

```
(Time.now+(Time.now.hour >= 4 ? 1 : 0).day).strftime("%Y-%m-%d 04:00:00").to_datetime
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the hour you are looking for using:

```
time = DateTime.now
time.change({hour: 4, min: 0, sec: 0})
```

this will give you a `time` variable at 04:00 am. You can then do `time+1` or `time-1` to move forward or backward one day at a time.

Eg. (saving one loc)

```
time = DateTime.now.change({hour: 4, min: 0, sec: 0})
time += 1 if time < DateTime.now
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following

```
time = Time.now.hour >= 4 ? Time.now+1.day : Time.now
time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d 04:00:00").to_datetime
```

Answer (score 1):

A little hacky:

```
if (DateTime.now.to_i - Date.today.to_datetime.to_i) > (60 * 60 * 4)
  next_4am = (Date.today + 1.day).to_datetime + 4.hours
else
  next_4am = Date.today.to_datetime + 4.hours
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
date, time = Time.now, [4,0,0]
date += 24*60*60 if date.hour >= 4
p Time.new(*date.to_a[3..5].reverse, *time) #=> 2013-11-20 04:00:00 +0100 

# date.to_a[3..5].reverse gets the date our from the Time object
```